# Cannot get custom dialog to show

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have the following code that is supposed to pop up a dialog and let the user select one of two choices by pressing a button. Unfortunately, it is not displaying. Past Reviews is "Y" but the getComponent line does not fire the dialog. What am I doing wrong?

```
<xp:button styleClass="btn btn-primary" value="Un-Cancel" id="button28">
 <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:GASODIDoc.getItemValueString("Status") == "Cancelled"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
 <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="norefresh" disableValidators="true">
<xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
if (GASODIDoc.getItemValueString("Past Reviews") == "Y"){
    getComponent('UnCancelDocument').show();
}
GASODIDoc.replaceItemValue("Status", sessionScope.status);
GASODIDoc.save();
context.redirectToPage("index.xsp")}]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

This is the dialog

```
<xe:dialog id="UnCancelDocument" styleClass="dialogForm">
        <xp:panel>
            <xp:panel styleClass="dialogRow">
                <xp:label
                    value="Do you want to return this GASODI to Draft or Document Generation status?">
                </xp:label>
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:panel>

        <!-- Save Button -->
        <xp:panel styleClass="dialogActions">
            <xp:button value="Return to Draft" styleClass="btn btn-primary"
                id="button51">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false"
                    immediate="true" save="false" disableValidators="true">                 
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[sessionScope.status = "Draft";
                    XSP.closeDialog('#{id:UnCancelDocument}')]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>

            <!-- Cancel Button -->
            <xp:button value="Return to Document Generation"
                styleClass="btn btn-primary" id="button52">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false"
                    immediate="true" disableValidators="true">                  
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[sessionScope.status = "Document Generation";
                    XSP.closeDialog('#{id:UnCancelDocument}')]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
        </xp:panel>
    </xe:dialog>
```

Comment: Does it redirect to index.xsp instead of showing the dialog?

Comment: Yes Per, it jumps right over the call to show the dialog

Comment: As expected since you can not launch a dialog and then process the rest of the code afterwards. You have to move your code to a button inside the dialog

Comment: Which code are you talking about? The code to launch the dialog or the code that sets the field values after it returns?

Comment: The code that sets the field values (so the code after showing the dialog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is as expected. The code actually runs and "displays" your dialog but then continues with the rest of the code which ends up in a redirect. In other words, the dialog does not block the rest of the code from running.

You need to move the rest of the logic to a button that the user clicks on inside the dialog as part of closing the dialog for instance.

Comment: Changing the UnCancel button to use <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent('UnCancelDocument').show();          }]]></xp:this.action> pops up the dialog and lets me set the status. Now I just have to figure out how to pop it up only if "Past Review" = "Y" but if "Past Review" = "N", set status to Draft without popping up the dialog